# Need clarification of TimeDistributed(dense()) with LSTM in many-to-many scenario

Tags: theano, keras, recurrent-neural-network, lstm, keras-layer

I am new to RNNs and keras.

I am trying to compare performance of LSTM against traditional machine learning algorithms (like RF or GBM) on a sequential data (not necessarily time-series but in order). My data contains 276 predictors and an output (for eg. stock price with 276 various informations of the stock's firm) with 8564 retro observations. Since, LSTMs are great in capturing sequential trend, I decided to use a time_step of 300. From the below figure, I believe I have the task of creating a many-to-many network (last figure from left). (Pic:http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/)

[image]

With each pink box being of size 276 (number of predictors) and 300 (time_steps) such pink boxes in one batch.However, I am struggling to see how I design the blue boxes here as each blue box should be the output (stock price) of each instance. From other posts on Keras gihub forum [#2403](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2403) and [#2654](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2654) , I think I have to implement TimeDistributed(Dense()) but I don't know how . This is my code to check if it works (train_idv is the data to predict from and train_dv is stock price)

```
train_idv.shape
#(8263, 300, 276)
train_dv.shape
#(8263, 300, 1)
batch_size = 1
time_Steps=300
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(300,
        batch_input_shape=(batch_size, time_Steps, train_idv.shape[2]),
        stateful=True, 
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(300))) 

# Model Compilation
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_idv, traindv, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

Running the model.fit gives this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 627, in fit
>       sample_weight=sample_weight)
>     File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1052, in fit
>       batch_size=batch_size)
>     File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 983, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='model target')
>     File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 111, in standardize_input_data
>       str(array.shape))
>   Exception: Error when checking model target: expected timedistributed_4 to have shape (1, 300, 300) but got array with shape (8263, 300, 1)

Now, I have successfully ran it with time_step=1 and just using Dense(1) as last layer. But I am not sure how should I shape my train_dv (output in training) or how to use TimeDistributed(Dense()) correctly. Finally, I want to use

```
trainPredict = model.predict(train_idv,batch_size=1)
```

to predict scores on any data.

I have posted [this question](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4381) on keras github forum as well.

Comment: I would be careful with TimeDistributed(Dense). Although it is essential in certain parts of the model (between LSTMs for example), I have found that it seems to break loss calculations if used as the final layer. See Keras on github for a  related issue: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/8055

Answer (score 3):

From your post I understand that you want each LSTM time step to predict a single scalar correct? Then you Time Distributed Dense layer should have output 1, not 300 (i.e. `TimeDistributed(Dense(1))`).

Also for your reference, there's an example in the keras repo for using [Time Distributed Dense](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/addition_rnn.py#L142).

In this example one wants basically to train a multi-class classifier (with shared weights) for each timestep, where the different possible classes are the different possible digit characters:

```
# For each of step of the output sequence, decide which character should be chosen
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(chars))))
```

The number of time steps is defined by the preceding recurrent layers.

Comment: Thanks for the help @cortex , the network is running now with improved performance.